# error with Xcode 6 'Duplicate interface definition for class 'ViewController'

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I'm programming an app following a basic tutorial from 2012 using Xcode 6. The tutorial was made using Xcode 4.3 and I'm sure I have followed it exactly as I have double checked by watching through the problem areas. I'm quite new to this type of programming as I usually deal with game development and robots but have done a little before.

error:

Duplicate interface definition for class 'ViewController'

This is the code:

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

 @interface ViewController // First error here.

 @end

 @implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

   -(void) presentMessage:(NSString *)message {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Title"         message: message delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil ];

[alert show];
[alert release]; // second error.
}

-(void) scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate {
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

...    

[notification release]; // third error
}

-(IBAction) buttonTapped:(id)sender {

    dateFormatter...

[dateFormatter release]; // fourth error
 }
   @end
```

Sorry about the weird formatting but I couldn't get this to format into code.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using ARC? You probably are so you can't call `release`.

Comment: BTW - a lot has changes since Xcode 4.3. Find a new tutorial.

Comment: @rmaddy yeah thanks i have released that and fixed it and that tutorial is the only one on the web in english that i could find and i spent hours looking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `()` to your `@interface ViewController` line.

`@interface ViewController()`

This is called a private category in iOS, and it's used to define private methods and properties in your implementation file.

In your .h file, you'll find the interface declared as `@interface ViewController`, and that's why the compiler thinks you're declaring it twice. Using a private category (`@interface ViewController()`) tells the compiler that you're actually extending the functionality of your already defined interface (called ViewController), adding private methods and properties.

Comment: From the looks of it, there is no need for the class extension in the .m file.

Comment: Absolutely not, but the error is given because of that...maybe he needs to add some properties or something there later in the tutorial, and should correct the issue now, even if the extension is empty yet.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution here..it worked for me

Go to edit scheme -> Select Build -> Build option untick the Parallelize Build

Now run your App